# Как создать переменные с помощью цикла?

Tags: python, pandas, for

Есть следующая таблица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"id": [1, 2, 3],
            "a" : [4, 5, 6],
            "b" : [7, 8, 9]})
df
```

Необходимо получить следующий вывод:

```
c1 = (4, 7)
c2 = (5, 8)
c3 = (6, 9)
```

В этом коде есть ошибка:

```
for i in range(0, int(df.shape[0])): 
    x[i] = (df.iloc[i, 1])
    y[i] = (df.iloc[i, 2])
    print(x[i], y[i])
    

for n in range(0, 2):      
    coordinates = [x[i], y[i]]
    c[n] = (coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
    print(c[n])
```

Comment: Пишите какого рода ошибка, и как вы её пытались решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же работаете с всемогущим Pandas - пользуйтесь хотя бы частичкой его мощи:

```
In [220]: c = df[["a", "b"]].to_numpy().tolist()

In [221]: c
Out[221]: [[4, 7], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
```

если вы абсолютно уверены, что строк всегда будет три:

```
In [222]: c1,c2,c3 = df[["a", "b"]].to_numpy().tolist()

In [223]: c1
Out[223]: [4, 7]

In [224]: c2
Out[224]: [5, 8]

In [225]: c3
Out[225]: [6, 9]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Можно ли ввод в 220 строке разбить на c1, c2, c3, ... с[n]?

Comment: @Panda,  в 220 строке создается __список__ `c`, к которому можно обращаться по индексу: `c[0], c[1], ..., c[n-1]`. Если вам нужны отдельные переменные и вам заранее известно количество записей в `df`, тогда смотрите пример ниже - строка 222

Comment: Понятно, круто, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вот то, что вы требовали:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"id": [1, 2, 3],
            "a" : [4, 5, 6],
            "b" : [7, 8, 9]})

res = []
x = [[]] * int(df.shape[0])
y = [[]] * int(df.shape[1])
for i in range(0, int(df.shape[0])): 
    x[i] = (df.iloc[i, 1])
    y[i] = (df.iloc[i, 2])
    res.append([x[i], y[i]])
    

for n, list_val in enumerate(res):      
    coordinates = list_val
    c = f'c{n + 1} = {(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])}'
    print(c)
```

Вывод:

```
c1 = (4, 7)
c2 = (5, 8)
c3 = (6, 9)
```

Comment: `str` не обязательно делать, можно просто `f'c{n+1} = {(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])}'`

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, я на всякий случай так сделал, просто были сомнения.

Comment: @Tehnorobot
Здесь имелось ввиду создание переменных

Comment: @Panda Понял, жаль, надеялся, что помог.

Comment: @Panda не нужно создавать нумерованными именами. Используйте списки/массивы - они для этого придуманы.